# Background ble scan in one plus

Tags: bluetooth, google, oneplus-6, asus-zenfone-3, nokia

We are trying to build an app which scan nearby Bluetooth devices and shows on the UI, we also have event listener which detects whenever location or bluetooth state is changed and accordingly we start the Bluetooth scan, we also make sure no more then 5 bleScan happens within 30 seconds.

Now heres the problem,
This app works fine for phones like Nokia, Asus etc, but for one plus what we have noticed is, whenever we are in background, and we disabled and enabled bluetooth, it dosent start the scan(in the code it reaching but no errors are been thrown) nor it throws error in onScanFailed callback, we didnt see this behavior in other phone

so it dosnet work if the setting is the following

[image]

but if we make the location "Allow all the time" , then it works perfectly

[image]

My question is who is doing it properly one plus or other phones? Am i missing some additional settings for one plus. please help

Comment: Hi while app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues, I'd assume this is asking for the behavior discrepancy between devices, which is still off-topic. That said, permissions that are related to user's privacy generally become stricter on the newer Android version. What are the Android versions of each device?

Comment: Apparently, I had a big typo yesterday... it was supposed to be "still *on*-topic" and that's why I didn't close the question. So, feel free to post the answer and possibly adding an explanation that is end-user-friendly :)

Comment: HI Andrew, Sorry wasnt aware of what we can post here, anyways i have found what the issue was basicaly the one plus which i was using had andriod version 11, and nokia and asus had andriod version 10. In Andriod 10,, and i completly misunderstood the differentce between  "Allow all the time" and "Allow only while using the app",
In Andriod 11, to give background permission , you need to go to App setttings and in permission select "Allow all the time" , because in Android 11, that "allow all the time" settings removed from the location popup

Comment: In "Allow only while using the app", calling startBleScan wont actually start the ble scan, n if u are unlucky the failure callback wont return an error also